# How to make mixin as sealed class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, mixins, sealed

How I can make mixin class "C" as sealed class cannot be extended outside its library?

```
class A extends B with C{}
sealed class B{}
mixin class C{}
```

I don't want C class to be used by a class other than "A" class

Comment: If `C` can be used only by `A`, what is the point of keeping `A` and `C` separate?

Comment: For more clear code in large models, class functionality can be divided .. you can see this way used, for example, in state management bloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tricky ways to accomplish this purpose:

mark your mixin as private mixin as you know (**privacy in dart is library level rather than class level**) so it can't be used outside it's library.

```
class A extends B with _C{}
sealed class B{}
mixin class _C{}
```

another way, you can convert your mixin to sealed class which achieve your purpose also, and *implement* it (**multiple inheritance is not allowed in dart:** ***Diamond Problem***)

```
class A extends B implements C{}
sealed class B{}
sealed class C{}
```

at last, class C can't be used outside the library in which it's declared, there may still other ways to accomplish your purpose. for more info see [Class Modifiers Reference](https://dart.dev/language/modifier-reference)

hope it helps you.